# python group strings in lists

Tags: python, string, list, grouping

I have two lists with the same `len`.

```
list1=[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
list2=['ATT', 'TTC', 'TCC', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CAA', 'AAA', 'AAG']
```

Note:

1). The number of elements in each list varies, but the two lists always have the same `len`.

2). `list1` only contains integers `0`, or `1`. It can only contain `0`s, only contain `1s`, or contain both `0s` and `1s`.

3). `list2` only contains strings with the same length, also for each string `k` (`k` is a index `>0`), `list2[k][:-1]=list2[k-1][1:]`, meaning that if `k=2, list[k]='TCC', list[k][:-1]='TC', list[k-1]='TTC', list[k-1][1:]='TC'`. Thus, `list2[k][:-1]=list2[k-1][1:]`.

I want to group the strings in `list2` based on their corresponding elements in `list1` (corresponding: elements in `list1` and `list2` sharing the same `index`). If `list1[n]==1`, then `list2[n-1]+list2[n][-1]`. If `list1[n]==0, and list1[n+1]==0, do nothing`.

e.g. the corresponding string of the first integer 1 in `list2` is `'TTC'`, then `'ATT'`, and `'TTC'` become `'ATTC'`. The corresponding string of the second integer 1 in list2 is `'TCC'`, then `'ATTC'` (Note; already combined), and `'TCC'` become `'ATTCC'`. Then `list1[3]==1`, `'ATTCC'` and `'CCC'` become `'ATTCCC'`. `list1[7]==1`, then `'AAG' ('AAG'=list2[7])` needs to be grouped with its previous string, `'AAA'`, the two become `'AAAG'`. The only condition that you do nothing is when `n=0`, and `n+1=0`. That's why, `list1[4]==0`, and `list1[4+1]==0`, `'CCA'` stays the same. `list1[5]==0`, and `list1[5+1]==0`, then `list2[5]='CAA'` remains unchanged.

After transformation, 
This is the output I want. 
`newlist2=['ATTCCC', 'CCA', 'CAA', 'AAAG']`

Obviously the code is not correct.

```
for i in range(1, len(list1)):
    if list1[i]==1:
        newlist2[i-1]+newlist2[i][-1]  
    else:
        do nothing
```

Comment: What happens when `list1[n]==0`, but `list1[n+1]!=0` (not equal zero)?

Comment: e.g. n=6,  list1[6]==0, but list1[6+1]==1, then list2[6+1]='AAG', 'AAG' needs to be combined with 'AAA', (list2[6]). The idea is as long as list1[n]=1, regardless of what list1[n-1] is, 0 or 1, list2[n] needs to be combined with its previous string, note that the previous string might already combined with the previous previous string, if this makes sense, like in the example I gave above, the way 'ATTCCC' was produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?:

```
list1=[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
list2=['ATT', 'TTC', 'TCC', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CAA', 'AAA', 'AAG']

indices = []
for i in range(1, len(list1)):
    if list1[i]==1:
        list2[i] = list2[i-1]+list2[i][-1]
        indices.append(i-1)


list2 = [list2[i] for i in range(len(list2)) if i not in indices]
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
['ATTCCC', 'CCA', 'CAA', 'AAAG']
```

I loop through your list, apply your method, and keep track of which indices I need to remove at the end, then I create a new list without the unnecessary indices.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with `functools.reduce`:

```
import itertools
import functools
list1=[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
list2=['ATT', 'TTC', 'TCC', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CAA', 'AAA', 'AAG']
d = [[a, [h for _, h in b]] for a, b in itertools.groupby(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_results = [i for b in filter(None, [[functools.reduce(lambda x, y:x+y[-1], [d[i-1][-1][-1]]+d[i][-1])] if d[i][0] else d[i][-1][:-1] for i in range(len(d))]) for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['ATTCCC', 'CCA', 'CAA', 'AAAG']
```

Comment: @JY078 Can you clarify your logic for how to achieve `['ATTCCC', 'CCA', 'CAA', 'AAAG']`? By strictly following the guideline you posted, `['ATTC', 'TTCC', 'TCCC', 'AAAG']` is the resulted output.

Comment: 1). if n=1, then you combine list2[n] with list2[n-1], so 'ATT' and 'TTC' become 'ATTC', then 'ATTC' and 'TCC' become 'ATTCC', then 'ATTCC' and 'CCC' become 'ATTCCC'. 'CCA', and 'CAA' stay the same, because n=0, also, n+1=0. Finally, 'AAA', and 'AAG' become 'AAAG', because 'AAG' in list1 is a 1, then 'AAG' needs to be combined with its previous string, 'AAA'.

Comment: @JY078 Thank you for the explanation. Please see my recent edit.